# Header Text from Microsoft Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I'm working on a project, which the fields for users to key in the data are unknown, users can create as many columns as they require.

I'm thinking to let the users to key in the data into Microsoft Access, and later call the data as DataGridView header text in Visual Studio by using VB.Net. But how about the fields for users to key in column value?

I'm looking for some suggestions for entering the column value.

Comment: **to key in column value** .. such as what ?

Comment: E.g. Book Title is the column header, and Bob The Dog is the column value.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx.aspx) to get your data.  Then use [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) to allow the user to edit the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm checking ADO.NET at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can get column name from your DataGridView

```
Dim sHeader As String = DataGridView1.Columns(0).Name
```

So you can set the cell value

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Item(n).Cells(sHeader).Value = "First"
```

Comment: But the columns (both header text and cell value) are created and entered by users, so I can't preset the DataGridView column. I'm planning to save the column header text created by users into Microsoft Access, and prepare the same number of columns programmatically, as the number of column headers created by users, so that the users can key in the cell value into the column created by them respectively.